# How to compute prices form daily returns?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with daily returns. I want to add another column with price series calculated based on daily returns.
This is the dataframe:

```
         date   daily
0  2020-09-01  0.0000
1  2020-09-02  0.0012
2  2020-09-03 -0.0005
3  2020-09-04 -0.0004
4  2020-09-07  0.0032
5  2020-09-08 -0.0015
6  2020-09-09  0.0005
7  2020-09-10  0.0003
8  2020-09-11  0.0001
9  2020-09-14  0.0043
10 2020-09-15  0.0037
11 2020-09-16 -0.0008
```

and this is the column of prices that i want to add:

```
       prices
0   100.000000
1   100.120000
2   100.069940
3   100.029912
4   100.350008
5   100.199483
6   100.249582
7   100.279657
8   100.289685
9   100.720931
10  101.093598
11  101.012724
```

I've tried to do a loop on column 'daily' and then calculate the price but i do not preserve the new values into the list prz.

```
prz= []

for row in df['daily']:
        prz.append(100 *(1+row))
```

Answer (score 1):

First add `1`, then use [`Series.cumprod`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumprod.html) and last multiply by `100`, for invert use [`Series.pct_change`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.pct_change.html) with replace first `NaN` to `0`:

```
df['prices'] = df['daily'].add(1).cumprod().mul(100)

df['back'] = df['prices'].pct_change().fillna(0)
print (df)
          date   daily      prices    back
0   2020-09-01  0.0000  100.000000  0.0000
1   2020-09-02  0.0012  100.120000  0.0012
2   2020-09-03 -0.0005  100.069940 -0.0005
3   2020-09-04 -0.0004  100.029912 -0.0004
4   2020-09-07  0.0032  100.350008  0.0032
5   2020-09-08 -0.0015  100.199483 -0.0015
6   2020-09-09  0.0005  100.249582  0.0005
7   2020-09-10  0.0003  100.279657  0.0003
8   2020-09-11  0.0001  100.289685  0.0001
9   2020-09-14  0.0043  100.720931  0.0043
10  2020-09-15  0.0037  101.093598  0.0037
11  2020-09-16 -0.0008  101.012724 -0.0008
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`numpy.cumproduct()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cumprod.html) here:

```
In [1349]: import numpy as np

In [1350]: df['prices'] = np.cumproduct(df.daily + 1) * 100

In [1351]: df
Out[1351]: 
          date   daily      prices
0   2020-09-01  0.0000  100.000000
1   2020-09-02  0.0012  100.120000
2   2020-09-03 -0.0005  100.069940
3   2020-09-04 -0.0004  100.029912
4   2020-09-07  0.0032  100.350008
5   2020-09-08 -0.0015  100.199483
6   2020-09-09  0.0005  100.249582
7   2020-09-10  0.0003  100.279657
8   2020-09-11  0.0001  100.289685
9   2020-09-14  0.0043  100.720931
10  2020-09-15  0.0037  101.093598
11  2020-09-16 -0.0008  101.012724
```